# Why is the console undefined when I store a simple jquery selector in a variable?

Tags: jquery

I want to add xml to my html using ajax but I can't seem to use jquery
to store a div in a variable that I need. When I call the variable on the console it returns undefined. At the moment I have:

```
var target = $(this).parent().find(".thread")[0];
    console.log(target);
```

The html I want to insert the xml in looks like this:

```
<div class="thread"></div>
```

Here is the javascript file:

```
var Threads = (function() {
var pub = {};




function produceThreads(data, target) {
    $(target).append("<ul>");

    $(data).find("thread").each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find("title")[0].textContent;
        var posts = $(this).find("posts")[0].textContent;
        $(target).append("<li>" + title + "</li>");
        $(target).append("<li>" + posts + "</li>");
        });
        $(target).append("</ul>");

    }



function showThreads() {

    var target = $(this).parent().find(".review")[0];
    console.log(target);

    var data = "forum.xml";

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        produceThreads(data, target);
    }
    });
    }



pub.setup = function() {
        showThreads();
    };

    return pub;
    }());

$(document).ready(Threads.setup);
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forum</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Forum.css">

    <script src="jQuery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Forum.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Forum</h1>
    </header>

<p>
<a href="users.html">users</a>
</p>
<div class="thread"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to have the xml list from the produceThreads function visible as soon as the html loads, but I can hardly have that when I can't even store a target variable. The jQuery version I am using is 1.10.2.min.

Comment: Why are you using $(this).parent().find() instead of just $()? It looks like the find method does not find anything.

Comment: Thank you Michiel you just solved it.